# How to create a packet in C#

Tags: c#, packets

I always wondered how could a game generate a packet like this:

```
22 00 11 00 6D 79 75 73 65 72 6E 61 6D 65 00 00 00 00 00 00 6D 79 70 61 73 73 77 6F 72 64 00 00 00 00 00 00

LENGTH-HEADER-USERNAME-PASSWORD
```

In the game code what should be their function or how do they write something like that? Is it simply `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Some String Values")`? Although I doubt it is written that way.

Every time I try to ask someone that, he thinks that I want to analyze packet. I don't - I want to know what I need to do in order to create a packet like the one above, in C#.

Comment: Considering how you responded negatively to a prevision link comment in an earlier similar question, I was reluctant to post this, but maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043621/create-a-network-packet-in-c-sharp-and-send-it-over-the-network) could help?

Comment: Game or Network packets?? More explanation is needed

Comment: this is a packet that was sniffed from a game.

Comment: -1. This question is missing code that show that you do know how to send something, it would be much easier to than reason how to send particular data.

Comment: the only way i know about sending a message is sending a string message like Hello World using socket.send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World"));. but i totally clues less how to send data message that contains the length id username password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course using a string builder is very far from packet structuring, you must use byte[] and append values to it by index.

Comment: thanks for your replay i noticed that from a time but your comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

The sample code you've put should convert the string to a byte array.  Depending which encoding you use (e.g. ASCII, Unicode, etc) you may get a different byte array from the same string.

The term packet is generally used when you're sending data through a network; but the packet itself is just the byte array.

The info you've got reads myUsername, myPassword.  The below C# code will translate for you.

```
        byte[] packet = new byte[] { 0x22, 0x00, 0x11, 0x00, 0x6D, 0x79, 0x75, 0x73, 0x65, 0x72, 0x6E, 0x61, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6D, 0x79, 0x70, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x77, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x64, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
        string test = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(packet);
        Console.WriteLine(test);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

So to create something similar I'd try:

```
    const int HeaderLength = 2;
    const int UsernameMaxLength = 16;
    const int PasswordMaxLength = 16;
    public static byte[] CreatePacket(int header, string username, string password)//I assume the header's some kind of record ID?
    {
        int messageLength = UsernameMaxLength + PasswordMaxLength + HeaderLength;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(messageLength+ 2);
        sb.Append((char)messageLength);
        sb.Append(char.MinValue);
        sb.Append((char)header);
        sb.Append(char.MinValue);
        sb.Append(username.PadRight(UsernameMaxLength, char.MinValue));
        sb.Append(password.PadRight(PasswordMaxLength, char.MinValue));
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString()); 
    }
```

Then call this code with:

```
byte[] myTest = CreatePacket(17, "myusername", "mypassword");
```

Comment: Ok i understand that, but what i want to know how was a packet like this created ? i mean how to write a data message for the server?

Comment: man i don't wanna to translate i want to know how something like this was created from (the packet) the beginning ?!!. Assuming i want to send a packet with that structure : size, header, username, password. WHAT SHOULD I DO ?

Comment: Take a look at the examples here, they may cover what you're after: http://www.csharp-examples.net/socket-send-receive/

Comment: Sorry although i don't wanna to annoy you with me i am begging for a right answer !. What i want is not sending Hello World. i want to know if i want to create a packet just like the above one what should i do ? (sending data that if sniffed give me the same as the above packet)